# How can I use archive-{post_type}.php theme template?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, templates, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I've got a `staff_member` custom post type, with `'has_archive' => true`. I've got an `archive-staff_member.php` template, with `/* Template Name: Staff */`

In backoffice, to add it to the nav menu, I created a page and assigned the template Staff, then added it to the main menu.

Till here, all fine. The problem is that when I navigate to the staff page, even if archive-staff_member.php is correctly loaded, wp_query is wrong. In other words, `is_post_type_archive()` and `is_post_type_archive('staff_member')` return false.

So what's the problem here?

For now I'm using just a custom query, but it would be better automated archive, as stated by official docs.

And by the way: it would be better if there was a way to add the archive from the menu page, instead of creating a 'dumb' staff page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, an answer to all. First, thank you for you help.

<strike>Anyway, none of your solutions really address my issue. I don't like custom links on nav menus, at all</strike>. And that's because they're not dynamic, you cannot build them dynamically. So <strike>when you move the site and change url (for example, from staging to production) you'll have to remember to manually change the links</strike>. Also, the client, who often is not a programmer, nor too used to computer/web/urls things, won't be able to properly manage it by himself.

**EDIT: I've found a solution to the above issue, so now Marek's answer can be considered reliable, at least to me: we can filter the nav_menu-generated urls so that they'll always use real site url:**

```
function normalize_url($atts){
    if( !parse_url($atts['href'], PHP_URL_SCHEME) && $atts['href'] != '#'){
        $atts['href'] = site_url() . $atts['href'];
    }
    return $atts;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'normalize_url');


//Marek's way will cause wp_nav_menu not to correctly 
//output parent/child  classes, so here's an example of 
//how to solve this issue too:
function fix_nav_classes($classes, $item){

    //say I've got some custom links: the 'Projects' parent and a child that 
    //points to '/selected_project/' and I want always these classes for both 
    //parents and child items
    if(is_post_type_archive('project') || get_post_type() == 'project'){
        if($item->post_title == 'Projects') $classes[] = 'current-menu-parent';
        if($item->url == '/selected_project/') $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'fix_nav_classes', 10, 2 );
```

**OLD ANSWER > good as alternative:**

The problem here, is that wordpress consider the 'page' nature first: if you assign a custom post type template (according to rules) to a page, that will not work. I think it's probably a permalink thing -> page has different permalink than the archive. I think I could fix just modifying the page's permalink OR the rewrite rule on register_post_type so that the 2 are the same, but this is not a good practice too.

So for now, just dumb page and a 'classic' custom query. For those who need, just this:

```
global $wp_query;

$query_array = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'post_type' => 'staff_member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$member = $wp_query->query($query_array);
```

I generally use this kind of code.. If one really needs all the wp sugar, he can also substitute the main query:

```
global $wp_query;
$original = $wp_query; // save for restore
$wp_query = new WP_Query();

$wp_query->query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'post_type' => 'staff_member',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

// here goes processing code and sugars
// if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); etc etc.. the_content() etc..

// restore the original
$wp_query = $original;
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Well, that is not ideal solution, but some workaround that could cause future complications. Correct way is described in my answer. If you do not like "custom links" in nav menu, then put there only relative URL, like "/staff_member/" ... and it will work for any domain website will run.

Comment: Above an edit that addresses the main issue of your approach. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Custom post type archive page does not need "dumb" Page. In fact, there could be the culprit. You should try this:

1. Remove `/* Template Name: Staff */` from archive-staff_member.php (not needed)
2. Remove "dumb" stuff Page (if created). There could be some permalink conflict.
3. Go to Admin > Settings > Permalinks and re-save it (it will regenerate rewrite rules)
4. Now just type URL ... yoursite.com/staff_member/ (depends on `rewrite` setting in your `register_post_type(...)` )

You should see only "staff member" posts. If yes, than wp_query is correct and `is_post_type_archive()` will returns true. If it uses correct archive template too, you are done :) If not (maybe 404 error?), then there is some misconfiguration.

And when you have `yoursite.com/staff_member/` URL, you can add it to nav menu as "Custom link". No "dumb" Page creation needed.

Comment: Ok, the problem here is that if for ex a staging site version is under a subdirectory (mydomain.com/subdir/), links will be wrongly built (mydomain.com/staff_member). I've posted below a filter code to solve this issue.

Comment: There's another problem following your way: nav_menu will not correctly output child/parent classes. I've posted a solution below.

Comment: Yes, another WP "feature" I don't like :-) But that was not part of your question, and I wanted my answer short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function is_post_type_archive only works in archive.php
To have an item on nav menu links to your staff_member, you will add a custom link menu item in stead of a page whose template is your file tempate.
The URL of that item will be got when you vardump this:

```
get_post_type_archive_link('staff_member')
```

And to custom the performance of the staff_member, use is_post_type_archive('staff_member') in the file archives.php of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `archive-{post_type}.php` when you create a custom post type and include this function: `flush_rewrite_rules();`

Make a page of your custom post type. It's called an archive page.